# Find $k$ such that the angle between the vectors $(2,k)$ and $ (3,5)$ is $60$ degrees

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vectors

I have $2$ vectors :  $U =(2,k)$    and  $V = (3,5)$. I want to find the $k$ value  when the angle between $U$ and $V$ is $60$ degrees.

This what I tried to do but I don't get the right answer :

$2\cdot3 + 5k = \sqrt{4+k^2} \cdot \sqrt{34} \cdot \cos60 \rightarrow  24k^2 +30.84k+5$

Comment: The idea is correct, but with so many steps missing I'm unable to tell what went wrong.

Comment: Because there so many steps , do you think it's possible to find the K value using another way ?

Answer (score 1):

The angle between V and the X axis is $arctan(5/3) = 59 \deg.$

Therefore, if $U$ is about 1 deg. below the X axis, the angle between U and V will be 60 degrees.

Now solve:

$k/2 = tan(-1)$

and get the solution.

Comment: k/3 = tan(-1) is -0.05 . This solution doesn't work when I try to validate .

Comment: Yes, $U=(2,-0.05)$ should be a possible solution. How did you try to validate?

Comment: just use the vectors on those function :  |U||V|cos60 =  Ux *Vx +Uy*Vy

Comment: Sorry, this should of course be $k/2$. So the solution is $U=(2,-0.035)$. Now $|U||V| \cos 60 = 2 * 5.83 * 0.5 = 5.83$, and $Ux *Vx +Uy*Vy = 2*3 - 5*0.035=5.83$